# Launch Jupyter Notebooks in AWS Sagemaker from a Custom Webapplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

We have a requirement where we are building a Webportal/platform that will use services of AWS and Git as both will host certain content to allow users to search for certain artifacts.

We also want to allow a user after they have searched for certain artifacts (lets say certain jupyter notebooks) to be able to launch these notebooks from our web-application. Note the notebooks are in different domain i.e AWS Console application host them.

Now, When user click on the notebook links from the webportal search it should open up the  Jupyter notebook in a notebook instance in a new tab.

We understand there is integration of AWS Sagemaker and GIT so some repos that will store notebooks can be configured. When user performs the search in webapp it will pick up the results from github API Call.

The same repos can also be added in the sagemaker-github integration  through AWS Console. So when a user launches the notebook he will see the github repos as well.

I understand we call Sagemaker API either through SDK or Rest API(not sure there is a rest api interface exploring on that). See a CLI call example -

aws sagemaker create-presigned-notebook-instance-url --notebook-instance-name notebook-sagemaker-git

this gives me a response url `"AuthorizedUrl": "https://notebook-sagemaker-git.notebook.us-east-2.sagemaker.aws?authToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmYXNDcmVkZW50aWFscyI6IkFZQURlQlR1NHBnZ2dlZGc3VTJNcjZKSmN3UUFYd0FCQUJWaGQzTXRZM0o1Y0hSdkxYQjFZbXhwWXkxclpYa0FSRUZvUVZadGMxSjFSVzV6V1hGVGJFWmphRXhWUTNwcVlucDZaR2x5ZDNGQ1RsZFplV1YyUkRoTGJubHRWRzVQT1dWM1RTdDBTR0p6TjJoYVdXeDJabnBrUVQwOUFBRUFCMkYzY3kxcmJYTUFTMkZ5YmpwaGQzTTZhMjF6T25WekxXVmhjM1F0TWpvMk5qZzJOek15TXpJMk5UUTZhMlY1THpObFlUaGxNMk14TFRSaU56a3RORGd4T0`

However, when i open this url it again asks me the aws console username and password. I feel in the webapp  when i logged in a user would already authenticate himself through AWS API as well as GIT API.

So there should be no need to re-authenticate themselves when they connect to AWS-Console to access their notebooks.

Is it something that can be circumvent using SIngle sign on etc.

thanks,
Aakash

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you get from a call to CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl is valid only for 5 minutes. If you try to use the URL after the 5-minute limit expires, you are directed to the AWS console sign-in page. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePresignedNotebookInstanceUrl.html

Jun